# How do I know if a QWebPage has finished loading?

Tags: qt4, qwebpage

Other than connecting a slot with QWebPage::loadFinished(), is there a way to poll its status? I didn't find a function that returns directly the percentage of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could connect to the loadProgress signal on QWebPage like so:

```
connect(webView, SIGNAL(loadProgress(int)), this, SLOT(loadProgress(int)));
```

This will report the percentage loaded as progress increases.